# Process Scheduling in Operating System

Tags: operating-system, scheduler

**Where does the Scheduler process run?**

I tried to search a lot about it, but couldn't find any relevant answer till now.

Comment: It runs on the computer, just like everything else does. What operating system are you talking about, for starters?

Comment: @ceejayoz:  Thanks for your wonderful reply.
But such kind answer was not expected by the interviewer.
It was asked in Amazon and DE-shaw & Co too.

Comment: They simply asked the question, without mentioning any specific O.S.

Comment: Then the answer is "on the computer" unless the job was specific to a particular operating system. There are [many implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Operating_system_process_scheduler_implementations) of schedulers.

Comment: The OS kernel thread/process scheduler/dispatcher is not a process.  cron/Task scheduler are kernel processes with user interfaces.  Summary: which scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the answer you are looking for is that (on most systems) the process scheduler is invoked through a timer interrupt. What ever process happens to be running at the time of the interrupt becomes the process scheduler as it executes in kernel mode.

Comment: The kernel thread scheduler can be invoked by syscalls from threads that are already running and I/O driver interrupts.  A timer interrupt is just one interrupt/driver amongst many.

Comment: True. I was trying to keep it simple given the question.

Answer (score 0):

The process scheduler is a part of the operating system that decides which process runs at a certain point in time. It usually has the ability to pause a running process, move it to the back of the running queue and start a new process.